# Cannot initialize UrlCache below iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

i need to implement cache and i have successfully implement it.

The problem is i have trouble to setup it when iOS version is below 13

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let cache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: Constants.memoryCacheByteLimit, diskCapacity: Constants.diskCacheByteLimit, directory: cacheURL)
    
    URLCache.shared = cache
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

> ''init(memoryCapacity:diskCapacity:directory:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

I use NSUrlCache, but it is already renamed to UrlCache, so must use this UrlCache for sure

Answer (score 1):

You can use this constructor.

```
{
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    let cache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: Constants.memoryCacheByteLimit, diskCapacity: Constants.diskCacheByteLimit, diskPath : "path") // path on disk where the cache data is stored
    URLCache.shared = cache
}
```